# utf8 encoded urls in rails 2.3.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I just upgraded Rails to 2.3.4. Before the upgrade rails was ok with international characters in urls, but it isn't working anymore.

How do I get the following to work with rails 2.3.4:

```
ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do |map|
    ...
    map.connect 'ö', :controller => 'test'
    ...
end
```

If I change 'ö' to 'o' it works, but thats not what I want.

Thanks,
Peder

Answer (score 1):

CGI::escape seems like a quick fix to me.

```
ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do |map|
  map.connect CGI::escape("ö"), :controller => 'test'
end
```